# Mysql ST_Contains return wrong result

Tags: mysql, geometry

I am using St_contains to find whether a point is in polygon, but the result seems to be inaccurate. If a point is not in the polygon, St_contains will still return 1.

here is my code

```sql
SET @i =  ST_GeomFromText
(
    'POLYGON((43.120825901794 -79.804519106556,43.121675995356 -79.808262109949,43.122060291437 -79.809953891553,43.122354803231 -79.811250508027,43.122502706668 -79.811978610103,43.122504906903 -79.811986283924,43.122508088955 -79.811996589915,43.122511303346 -79.812006400094,43.122515398461 -79.812018485988,43.122519502329 -79.812029908205,43.122524189401 -79.812042396061,43.122529607259 -79.812055910908,43.122534497156 -79.812067301339,43.122539412616 -79.812078511034,43.122544813239 -79.812089906984,43.122551308513 -79.812103104857,43.122556500525 -79.812113197823,43.122556947646 -79.81211402064,43.122561101914 -79.81212180938,43.122567611947 -79.812133297692,43.12257380731 -79.812143998195,43.122581413338 -79.812156209043,43.122588306761 -79.812166796322,43.122597209243 -79.812179886041,43.122606608303 -79.812192880573,43.122615299471 -79.812204285086,43.122624697158 -79.812215817893,43.122632697612 -79.812225210299,43.122640110139 -79.812233503458,43.122647597468 -79.812241602988,43.122654393768 -79.812248595486,43.122657689796 -79.81225190959,43.122665191582 -79.812259204694,43.122669705582 -79.812263383434,43.122673696679 -79.812267107346,43.122678788478 -79.812271587283,43.122683499255 -79.812275714497,43.122688998725 -79.812280192156,43.122693910958 -79.812284301463,43.122704110012 -79.812292282669,43.122706800281 -79.812294188955,43.122715799598 -79.812300708994,43.122730907194 -79.812312591598,43.122740295329 -79.812321516184,43.122746889145 -79.812328700988,43.122754011258 -79.812337105016,43.122760200793 -79.812345405227,43.122766789948 -79.812355097555,43.12277320192 -79.81236570656,43.12277941111 -79.812377413051,43.122783094344 -79.812385116304,43.122788695772 -79.812398304727,43.122793496059 -79.812411598466,43.122796593147 -79.812421300181,43.122799710508 -79.812432597886,43.122802193416 -79.812443191512,43.122803993055 -79.812452188659,43.122805891151 -79.812463701229,43.122806890277 -79.81247099346,43.122808511891 -79.812488705099,43.122809106538 -79.812503100133,43.122809109847 -79.812515282914,43.122808503102 -79.81253020137,43.122807204003 -79.812545092356,43.122805708405 -79.812556588469,43.122803493502 -79.812569317318,43.122800909017 -79.812581411864,43.122799110463 -79.812588392426,43.122797795926 -79.812593192326,43.122789308453 -79.812618807415,43.122785206163 -79.812630081095,43.122779307318 -79.812647986598,43.122773098226 -79.812668584165,43.122767591602 -79.812690007256,43.122761402516 -79.812718188204,43.12275719202 -79.812741395308,43.122753597693 -79.812765903096,43.122750802611 -79.812793195292,43.122750127663 -79.812802910099,43.122748997299 -79.812819183992,43.122748294917 -79.81283959272,43.12274821248 -79.812861510037,43.122748690312 -79.812882514783,43.122750411098 -79.81291109605,43.122752695783 -79.812933890352,43.122755301773 -79.812954616298,43.122758590734 -79.812975302669,43.122763193312 -79.812998986918,43.12276340289 -79.813000115557,43.122763695683 -79.813001292097,43.122763890121 -79.81300249433,43.122764303539 -79.81300489243,43.122764692381 -79.813007296966,43.122764989888 -79.813008507055,43.122765208902 -79.813009702853,43.122765792147 -79.813013309692,43.122766294518 -79.813015614871,43.122766513532 -79.813016810669,43.122766707928 -79.813018012913,43.122766902374 -79.813019215204,43.122767286494 -79.813021586131,43.122767608576 -79.813022789786,43.122767803022 -79.813023992078,43.122767997417 -79.813025194322,43.122768191856 -79.813026396555,43.122768694226 -79.813028701735,43.122768888629 -79.813029904037,43.122769107643 -79.813031099835,43.122769690888 -79.813034706674,43.122770013004 -79.81303591026,43.122770207408 -79.813037112563,43.122770401846 -79.813038314796,43.122770596249 -79.813039517099,43.122770790644 -79.813040719343,43.122771093897 -79.81304178867,43.1227712883 -79.813042990973,43.122771507314 -79.813044186771,43.12277170176 -79.813045389063,43.122771896155 -79.813046591307,43.122772193661 -79.813047801397,43.122772388099 -79.813049003631,43.12277260712 -79.813050199487,43.122772801515 -79.813051401732,43.122772995918 -79.813052604035,43.122773303885 -79.813053706912,43.122773498288 -79.813054909215,43.122774106142 -79.81305850955,43.122774398926 -79.813059686031,43.122774593372 -79.813060888323,43.122775201183 -79.813064488669,43.122775498731 -79.813065698749,43.12277589799 -79.813067996083,43.122776092393 -79.813069198386,43.122776389898 -79.813070408477,43.122776608911 -79.813071604275,43.122777192189 -79.813075211045,43.122777509557 -79.813076381151,43.122777703994 -79.813077583384,43.122778107974 -79.813079914327,43.122778400766 -79.813081090868,43.12277859516 -79.813082293113,43.122778789606 -79.813083495405,43.122779008619 -79.813084691203,43.122779203013 -79.813085893448,43.122779500519 -79.813087103539,43.122779694964 -79.813088305831,43.122779899828 -79.813089400921,43.122780094222 -79.813090603166,43.122780391727 -79.813091813256,43.122780610749 -79.813093009114,43.12278099958 -79.813095413592,43.122781292372 -79.813096590133,43.122781486766 -79.813097792378,43.122781705787 -79.813098988235,43.122781900224 -79.813100190469,43.122782208155 -79.813101293416,43.122782402593 -79.81310249565,43.122782791432 -79.813104900187,43.122783088937 -79.813106110278,43.12278330795 -79.813107306076,43.122783696746 -79.813109710625,43.12278398958 -79.813110887155,43.122784199114 -79.813112015806,43.122784612572 -79.813114413897,43.122784905355 -79.81311559038,43.122785488597 -79.813119197221,43.12278581072 -79.813120400866,43.122785990965 -79.813121502402,43.122786209977 -79.813122698201,43.122786404379 -79.813123900505,43.122786701919 -79.813125110526,43.122787309735 -79.813128710933,43.122787602518 -79.813129887415,43.122788001826 -79.813132184798,43.122788299331 -79.813133394889,43.122788907182 -79.813136995226,43.122789204686 -79.813138205317,43.12278939908 -79.813139407563,43.122789593525 -79.813140609855,43.122789901447 -79.813141712744,43.122790095892 -79.813142915037,43.122790509298 -79.813145313081,43.122790802089 -79.813146489623,43.122790996482 -79.813147691868,43.122791190927 -79.813148894161,43.122791488432 -79.813150104252,43.122791887688 -79.813152401588,43.122792106708 -79.813153597446,43.122792404204 -79.813154807479,43.122792598649 -79.813156009771,43.122792793042 -79.813157212017,43.122793085833 -79.813158388558,43.122793304845 -79.813159584358,43.122793704109 -79.813161881752,43.122794001657 -79.813163091833,43.122794390443 -79.813165496324,43.122794712566 -79.813166699969,43.122794906968 -79.813167902273,43.122795101404 -79.813169104507,43.122795409334 -79.813170207455,43.122795603771 -79.81317140969,43.122795798172 -79.813172611994,43.122795992608 -79.813173814228,43.122796309966 -79.813174984276,43.122796698803 -79.813177388815,43.122796996308 -79.813178598907,43.12279720117 -79.813179693997,43.122797395614 -79.81318089629,43.122797693118 -79.813182106382,43.12279791213 -79.813183302181,43.122798106523 -79.813184504427,43.122798404027 -79.813185714519,43.122798803291 -79.813188011914,43.122799096116 -79.813189188386,43.122799290517 -79.81319039069,43.122799509528 -79.81319158649,43.122799807032 -79.813192796582,43.122800400731 -79.813196296212,43.122800698235 -79.813197506304,43.122800892628 -79.813198708549,43.122801111648 -79.813199904408,43.122801409152 -79.8132011145,43.122801598874 -79.813202283184,43.122801793266 -79.81320348543,43.122802101239 -79.813204588367,43.122802295632 -79.813205790613,43.122802490068 -79.813206992848,43.122802812147 -79.813208196505,43.122803006591 -79.813209398798,43.122803200984 -79.813210601044,43.122803498487 -79.813211811136,43.122803703349 -79.813212906227,43.122804000853 -79.813214116319,43.122804195289 -79.813215318554,43.122804409543 -79.813216480815,43.12280470709 -79.813217690896,43.122804901491 -79.813218893201,43.122805095883 -79.813220095447,43.122805403856 -79.813221198384,43.122805598248 -79.81322240063,43.122805792692 -79.813223602923,43.122806090187 -79.813224812957,43.122806503599 -79.813227211061,43.122806796389 -79.813228387604,43.122807001251 -79.813229482695,43.122807195686 -79.81323068493,43.122807493189 -79.813231895022,43.122807906601 -79.813234293127,43.122808204104 -79.813235503219,43.12280839854 -79.813236705454,43.122808706469 -79.813237808403,43.122808900905 -79.813239010638,43.122809095305 -79.813240212943,43.122809388086 -79.813241389426,43.122809607105 -79.813242585285,43.122809801541 -79.81324378752,43.12281010947 -79.813244890469,43.122810303905 -79.813246092704,43.122810601409 -79.813247302796,43.122810990244 -79.813249707336,43.122811312323 -79.813250910994,43.122811506758 -79.813252113229,43.122811711576 -79.813253208332,43.122812004409 -79.813254384863,43.122812198801 -79.813255587109,43.122812496304 -79.813256797202,43.122812909715 -79.813259195307,43.122813193103 -79.813260304621,43.122813412079 -79.813261500491,43.122813606514 -79.813262702726,43.122813904017 -79.813263912819,43.122814098409 -79.813265115065,43.122814391241 -79.813266291597,43.122814790494 -79.813268588935,43.122815087997 -79.813269799028,43.122815307016 -79.813270994887,43.122815604519 -79.813272204979,43.122816003772 -79.813274502317,43.122816301274 -79.81327571241,43.122816690109 -79.813278116951,43.122817007509 -79.813279286989,43.122817201909 -79.813280489294,43.122817509872 -79.813281592173,43.122817704272 -79.813282794479,43.122818001775 -79.813284004572,43.122818390601 -79.813286409054,43.122818712723 -79.8132876127,43.122818892965 -79.813288714238,43.122819210372 -79.813289884335,43.122819599207 -79.813292288876,43.122819896709 -79.813293498969,43.122820091101 -79.813294701216,43.122820399073 -79.813295804154,43.122820812474 -79.813298202201,43.122821109977 -79.813299412294,43.12282130442 -79.813300614588,43.1228215972 -79.813301791073,43.122821802061 -79.813302886165,43.12282199646 -79.81330408847,43.122822293963 -79.813305298563,43.122822488397 -79.813306500799,43.122822810475 -79.813307704457,43.12282300491 -79.813308906693,43.122823312838 -79.813310009642,43.122823701672 -79.813312414183,43.122823994452 -79.813313590668,43.122824188895 -79.813314792962,43.122824510965 -79.813315996562,43.122824691258 -79.813317098148,43.122824988752 -79.813318308182,43.122825402161 -79.813320706289,43.122825699663 -79.813321916382,43.122825904524 -79.813323011474,43.122826197312 -79.813324188017,43.122826391746 -79.813325390253,43.122826689248 -79.813326600347,43.122826908258 -79.813327796147,43.12282720576 -79.813329006241,43.122827410621 -79.813330101333,43.12282760502 -79.813331303639,43.122827902522 -79.813332513732,43.122828096956 -79.813333715968,43.122828389744 -79.813334892512,43.122828594604 -79.813335987604,43.122828892106 -79.813337197697,43.122829111116 -79.813338393498,43.122829408618 -79.813339603592,43.122829603009 -79.813340805839,43.122829797451 -79.813342008134,43.122830105371 -79.813343111025,43.122830299813 -79.813344313319,43.122830592593 -79.813345489804,43.122830786992 -79.81334669211,43.122831109104 -79.813347895699,43.122831289354 -79.813348997296,43.122831611466 -79.813350200885,43.122831805865 -79.813351403191,43.122832103367 -79.813352613285,43.122832297801 -79.813353815521,43.122832502661 -79.813354910613,43.122832795449 -79.813356087157,43.122832989839 -79.813357289404,43.122833287341 -79.813358499498,43.12283350635 -79.813359695299,43.122833789703 -79.813360804684,43.122834008712 -79.813362000485,43.122834306214 -79.813363210579,43.122834500656 -79.813364412874,43.122834793435 -79.813365589359,43.122834987834 -79.813366791665,43.122835295797 -79.813367894546,43.122835490195 -79.813369096852,43.122835812307 -79.813370300441,43.122836006706 -79.813371502747,43.122836509067 -79.813373807933,43.12283680189 -79.813374984407,43.122837190679 -79.813377388961,43.12283769304 -79.813379694148,43.122837990585 -79.81338090423,43.122838209551 -79.813382100043,43.122838701493 -79.813384512432,43.122839004742 -79.813385581763,43.122839199133 -79.81338678401,43.122839496634 -79.813387994104,43.122839691075 -79.813389196399,43.122839988568 -79.813390406435,43.122840193436 -79.813391501586,43.122840490929 -79.813392711622,43.122841002725 -79.813395083968,43.122841197124 -79.813396286274,43.122841505086 -79.813397389155,43.122841699485 -79.813398591461,43.122841996986 -79.813399801555,43.122842191419 -79.813401003792,43.122842513495 -79.813402207451,43.122842693779 -79.813403308979,43.12284299128 -79.813404519073,43.122843205575 -79.813405681325,43.122843503076 -79.813406891419,43.122843707936 -79.813407986512,43.122844005437 -79.813409196606,43.122844199827 -79.813410398854,43.122844497328 -79.813411608949,43.12284469176 -79.813412811185,43.122844999688 -79.813413914136,43.122845194121 -79.813415116373,43.122845486908 -79.813416292917,43.122845809028 -79.813417496565,43.122846003417 -79.813418698813,43.122846311388 -79.813419801753,43.122846997711 -79.813423416332,43.122847290498 -79.813424592877,43.12292490524 -79.813778482048,43.123728589986 -79.817340495521,43.123819001797 -79.817730797992,43.125562096479 -79.82526180161,43.126352290224 -79.828680091806,43.126371493927 -79.828764987565,43.127407795926 -79.833244795444,43.129189298146 -79.841079299819,43.129566009762 -79.842707403722,43.128570609264 -79.843119504623,43.127118002929 -79.843724698354,43.126588898469 -79.843943683782,43.119640788552 -79.846975508053,43.116269602609 -79.848427805095,43.115463209268 -79.848823994691,43.113553793286 -79.849683312169,43.113553715867 -79.849683123551,43.111654261814 -79.841693177344,43.111654208955 -79.841692982329,43.110268846789 -79.835610897079,43.110268793917 -79.835610702076,43.109590047052 -79.832624887046,43.109589994225 -79.832624692097,43.108344757178 -79.827081207958,43.108344704287 -79.827081012972,43.107372852097 -79.822761396678,43.107372799197 -79.822761201701,43.106127695209 -79.817279292439,43.104760196603 -79.811320584182,43.106392005228 -79.810637687702,43.111636709371 -79.808422109977,43.114581813649 -79.80715971253,43.117057714176 -79.80609846923,43.117463786158 -79.805924387244,43.118438988571 -79.805514488995,43.12053000068 -79.804635487977,43.120825901794 -79.804519106556))',
    4326
);

set @j = ST_GeomFromText('Point(43.6645419 -79.8133914)', 4326);

SELECT ST_Contains(@i, @j)
```

[MySQL Online compiler](https://paiza.io/projects/_awiKJL2mK1bbG5rtOIK6w)

and here is the map,  which shows the position of point and polygon

[polygon & point position in map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp6D4.jpg)

I have been searching for a long time and still don't know where the problem is. Please help me to check it out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just used your link to MySQL compiler and got a `0` for the above point...

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski you get `0` maybe because I changed the order of the st_contains parameters before.

ST_Contains(@i, @j) is the right order, can you run it again to see if it is `0` now?